# 2d histogram making

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a data file containing two columns, like

```
1.1 2.2
3.1 4.5
1.2 4.5
3.2 4.6
1.1 2.3
4.2 4.9
4.2 1.1
```

I would like to make a histogram from the two columns, i.e. to get this output (if the step size (or **bin size**, as we talking about histogramming) equals to **0.1** in this case)

```
1.0 1.0 0
1.0 1.1 0
1.0 1.2 0
...
1.1 1.0 0
1.1 1.1 0
1.1 1.2 0
...
1.1 2.0 0
1.1 2.1 0
1.1 2.2 1
...
...
```

Can anybody suggest me something? It would be nice, if I can set the the range of values of the colmuns. In the above case the 1st column values goes from 1 to 4, and the same as for the second column.

**EDITED:** *updated in order to handle more general data input, e.g. float numbers. The step size in the above case is 0.1, but it would be nice if it can be tunable for other settings, i.e. if step range (**bin size**) is for example 0.2, or **1.0**. 
If the step size is for example 1.0, then if I have 1.1 and 1.8 they have the same bin, we have to handle them together, for example (the range in this case let us say 4 for both of the two columns 0.0 ... 4.0)*

```
1.1 1.8
2.5 2.6
1.4 2.1
1.3 1.5
3.3 4.0
3.8 3.9
4.0 3.2
4.0 4.0
```

output (**if the bin size = 1.0**)

```
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 3 0
1 4 0

2 1 0
2 2 1
2 3 0
2 4 0

3 1 0
3 2 0
3 3 1
3 4 1

4 1 0
4 2 0
4 3 1
4 4 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the histogram of `4 1` be 1?

Comment: Yes, of course, I did a mistake, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'END {
  for (i = 0; ++i <= l;) {
    for (j = 0; ++j <= l;)
      printf "%d %d %d %s\n", i, j, \
        b[i, j], (j < l ? x : ORS) 
    }
  }
{
  f[NR] = $1; s[NR] = $2
  b[$1, $2]++
  }' l=4 infile
```

You may try this (not thoroughly tested):

```
awk -v l=4 -v bs=0.1 'BEGIN {
  if (!bs) {   
   print "invalid bin size" > "/dev/stderr"
   exit
    }
  split(bs, t, ".")
  t[2] || fl++
  m = "%." length(t[2]) "f" 
  }
{
  fk = fl ? int($1) : sprintf(m, $1)
  sk = fl ? int($2) : sprintf(m, $2)
  f[fk]; s[sk]; b[fk, sk]++
  }

END {
  if (!bs) exit 1

  for (i = 1; int(i) <= l; i += bs) {
    for (j = 1; int(j) <= l; j += bs) {
      if (fl) {
        fk = int(i); sk = int(j); m = "%d"
        }
      else {
        fk = sprintf(m, i); sk = sprintf(m, j)
        }     
      printf "%s" m OFS m OFS "%d\n", (i > 1 && fk != p ? ORS : x), fk, sk, b[fk, sk]
      p = fk        
      }
    }
  }'  infile
```

Comment: Hi, nice! How can I tune it in a way that it can be capable to use float numbers, i.e. for example 1.45, 3.1230, 2.101, ...etc. ?

Comment: Hi @user1116360, which awk version are you using? The solution will depend on your awk implementation.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, awk version: GNU Awk 3.1.6 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: Hi @user1116360, could you also post sample data and an example of the desired output with floating point numbers? I mean, if you have 1, 1.2, 3 in the first column what should be the range: 1, 1.2, 2, 3 or 1, 1.2, 2, 2.2, 3, 3.2 ... ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in bash:

```
for x in {1..4} ; do
    for y in {1..4} ; do
        echo $x%$y 0
    done
done \
| join -1 1 -2 2 - -a1 <(sed 's/ /%/' FILE \
                         | sort \
                         | uniq -c \
                         | sort -k2 ) \
| sed 's/ 0 / /;s/%/ /'
```

It creates the table with all zeros in the last column, joins it with the real results (classic frequency table `sort | uniq -c`) and removes the zeros from the lines where a different number should be shown.

Comment: Very complicated, `fgrep` can handle this in a much easier way, see my answer

Comment: @fge: I've seen it. You are calling fgrep many times which can make the script slower for longer tables.

Comment: Well, you call sed, then join, then sort, then uniq, then sort, then sed again ;)

Comment: @fge: Yeah. And that's it, 6 calls for a table of any size. You have 4*4=16 calls to fgrep even for 4x4.

Answer (score 0):

One solution in perl (sample output and usage to follow):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use strict;

my ($min, $step, $max, $file) = @ARGV
    or die "Syntax: $0 <min> <step> <max> <file>\n";

my %seen;

open F, "$file"
    or die "Cannot open file $file: $!\n";

my @l = map { chomp; $_}  qx/seq $min $step $max/;

foreach my $first (@l) {
    foreach my $second (@l) {
        $seen{"$first $second"} = 0;
    }
}

foreach my $line (<F>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line or next;
    $seen{$line}++;
}

my $len = @l; # size of list
my $i = 0;

foreach my $key (sort keys %seen) {
    printf("%s %d\n", $key, $seen{$key});
    $i++;
    print "\n" unless $i % $len;
}

exit(0);
```

Comment: What if I have "float" numbers, 1.4 5.4 23.14,...etc. Can we tune it according to this requirement?

Comment: As I said, this is very tied to your data, if your data set is more general than this, can you edit your question to describe the whole problem set?*

Comment: OK, removing my answer since I cannot do anything if the whole problem set is not described.

Comment: After the fixes, it should fully answer your needs

Comment: Thanks, fge! Just one more simple question: I would like to add a new line (generally) after every new outer for loop beginning; for example in your answer in the integer case after these lines 1 4 1, 2 4 0, ...

Comment: Doable if the final loop is adapted a little... Hold on a few minutes, I'll cook that up

Comment: Done. Trimmed sample output, since it made the post reaaally too long.